# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected predictions to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (256, 1, 1)

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I'm trying to train a model Keras but I'm having a problem:

```
g = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True,
                    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
                    rotation_range=45,
                    width_shift_range=0.2,
                    height_shift_range=0.2,
                    horizontal_flip=True,
                    validation_split=validation_split,
                    preprocessing_function=lambda x: x / 127 - 1)

g_train = g.flow(x_train, y_train,
             batch_size=batch_size,
             subset='training')

g_valid = g.flow(x_train, y_train,
             batch_size=batch_size,
             shuffle=False,
             subset='validation')


history = network.fit_generator(g_train,
                          steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) / 32, 
                          epochs=epochs)

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected predictions to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (256, 1)
```

Someone have any idea why? It seems much like the example in documentation to me.

```
x_train.shape
(50000, 32, 32, 1)
y_train.shape
(50000, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Can you print the shapes of `x_train` and `y_train`?

Comment: x_train.shape
(50000, 32, 32, 1)
y_train.shape
(50000, 1, 1)

Comment: Read this [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6351). As per this, you need to add flatten(). There is a mismatch in the dimension.

Comment: I add flatten(). New error: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected predictions to have shape (100,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: you can use `model.summary` and check dimensions on each layer and it should help to find where are dimensions getting wrong.